# how to get polynomial equation from points

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions

How can i get polynomial equation from points?
I have data in excel and i want to get polynomial equation from it. I can get polynomial equation using excel using trendline but only to order of 6.
I would like to know how does excel get polynomial equation just with the points.  the graph and the equation is shown in the picture 
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RPKm.png)

Comment: Do you knwo polynomial regression ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this most easily with matrices, and  a quick Google search shows that matrix multiplication can be done in Excel, but it can be a bit of a pain, especially with so many points.

Let $A$ be the matrix created from the system of equations that result from plugging each point into $f(x)$ and $y$ be the matrix containing the values of $f(x)$. So given a set of points $\{(x_1, y_1),(x_2, y_2),...,(x_n, y_n)\}$, if you want a polynomial fit of degree $N$ (with $N>n$), you'd have the following matrices:

$A = \begin{bmatrix} x_1^{N} & x_1^{N-1} &  x_1^{N-2} & ... & 1 \\  x_2^{N} & x_2^{N-1} &  x_2^{N-2} & ... & 1 \\ \vdots & \vdots &  \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ x_n^{N} & x_n^{N-1} &  x_n^{N-2} & ... & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

$Y = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{bmatrix}$

Now take set the matrix $\beta$ as

$$\beta = (A^T A)^{-1} A^T Y$$ whose elements are the coefficients of the $N$th degree polynomial corresponding to the set of points.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, if you are graphing the data points, then you can just select the **polynomial order** to be 6, and then tick the checkbox to say that you wish "**display equation on chart**". This is explained in detail here: ["Excel best fit line curve function"](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2642-excel-best-fit-line-curve-function.html)

However, if you wish to obtain the equation of the polynomial via cell formulae and not as a chart feature, then you need to either leverage the less documented features of LINEST.

This is explained:

- [Does Excel have a function similar to LINEST, that fits a polynomial instead of a linear equation? If not, how can I accomplish this?](https://www.quora.com/Does-Excel-have-a-function-similar-to-LINEST-that-fits-a-polynomial-instead-of-a-linear-equation-If-not-how-can-I-accomplish-this),
- ["Quadratic and cubic regression in excel"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857252/quadratic-and-cubic-regression-in-excel)